# Is there a CLI for CCRC version 7.0.1

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Is there a command-line interface (CLI) for version 7.0.1 of the ClearCase Remote CLient (CCRC)?

The [only CCRC CLI information I can find](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg24021929) seems to only be relevant for version 7.1.  I tried downloading that, but it doesn't seem to work with version 7.0.1. (and its no surprise, as 7.0.1 is not listed as being compatible).

So, is it possible to interact with CCRC via the command line/shell scripts?

Comment: Just added some links to consolidate the documentation part of this answer.

Comment: Reminder: you can have a VOB server 7.0.x, ***and*** a CM Server 7.1.1 with 7.1.1 CCRC clients: that would solve your problem. The "Upgrading the Rational ClearCase Remote Client" link I have added in my answer appears to points to that.

Comment: Fair warning however: the installation process (of Vob Server, CM server or CCRC client) is radically different between 7.0.x products and 7.1 products. For the CM server in particular, I have spent *long* hours setting this one up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I do confirm you cannot have a 7.1 CCRC client with a 7.0.x cCRC server. You would get in the logs:

```
[1/14/10 10:19:47:555 CET] 0000001f CMLogger      E   
  CRVSV0571I Exception reason code: incompatible-server
[1/14/10 10:19:47:556 CET] 0000001f CMLogger      E   
  CRVSV1014E Client is too new to use this server. 
             Maximum version accepted: 7.1.0.2
```

As I experienced 15 days ago;) (And that was between 7.1.0 server and 7.1.1 client...)
See:

- [Upgrading the Rational ClearCase Remote Client](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_inst_upgr_ccrc.htm), and
- [System Requirements for the ClearCase Remote Client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21224586).

---

As mentioned by [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=248288) (or [this one](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14207094&#14207094)), CCRC CLI is strictly a 7.1 effort, announced during the [IBM Rational Software Conference of 2009](https://www-950.ibm.com/events/wwe/grp/grp021.nsf/vLookupPDFs/9%20HELMUS%20CC%20&%20CQ%20Developments/$file/9%20HELMUS%20CC%20&%20CQ%20Developments.pdf) (see slide 10), with a:

- ClearWaN (CCRC CLI) only available in post 7.1 (2009, late 2009 as it turned out)
- [CM API (Java Based)](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.team_api.doc/topics/c_cm_api.htm) only for Web views in 2009, Web and dynamic views in 2010 and all view type inn 2011.

Comment: Damn, that wasn't the answer I wanted, but thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

This page clarifies which versions of ClearCase server and client are supposed to work with CCRC CLI.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&context=SSSH27&dc=D400&uid=swg24021929&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8&lang=en&rss=ct984rational

Comment: Isn't that the same link I posted in the question? Or is it different?